# Android: show a download progress bar as in DownloadManager

Tags: android, download, notifications, download-manager

I want to download file from a server and show the progress in a notification progress bar as when using the DownloadManager class. I don't want to use the DownloadManager class because it only can save to external memory while I want my file to be saved internally. What to do ?

Comment: You could take some inspiration from this: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/tut-splashscreen-with-progress-bar/

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using AsyncTask or ProgressDialog. Would either of these work?

[Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)

Comment: Yes, I tried the link you gave, but I have a problem: I can not pull down the notification bar. (I used the asynctask method).

Comment: yes, it works. But I have a problem: i cannot pull down the notification bar